# Fetching a bitmap from GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps

New to GoogleMaps and am wondering, before I really dig in, if there is even a way to do what I need... (don't want to waste time discovering I am hunting a unicorn)

I would like to submit some georeference data to GM (ie, center lat/long, width & height in feet or degrees, angle of rotation, satellite or streets) and get back a bitmap/jpg/png of the map described (maybe even a worldfile?)

Possible?  If so, what facet of the API should I be investigating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the Google Maps Image APIs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/?hl=nl